# Разделить строку на 2 части PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть строка с именем. Как мне ее разделить на 2 части. 1 часть до пробела, а 2 после. К примеру "Иван Иванов" и сделать раздельно "Иван" и "Иванов"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'Иван Иванов';
$result = explode(' ',$str);
//теперь $result массив
echo 'Имя ' . $result[0];
echo 'Фамилия' . $result[1];
```

Comment: Либо `list($name, $surname) = explode(" ", $str);`